# Error parsing AppSettings value with a query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, web-config, appsettings

In my AppSettings in `web.config`, I have something like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ExternalSystemUrl" value="http://example.com/page.aspx?id={0}&action=eat&object=bacon" />
</appSettings>
```

However, it seems that when an ampersand (`&`) is included in an AppSettings value, ASP.NET throws the following error:

> An error occurred while parsing EntityName

Why does this happen, and how can I include URLs like this in `App.config`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Replace `&` with `&amp;` (escape it):

```
<add
    key="ExternalSystemUrl"
    value="http://example.com/page.aspx?id={0}&amp;action=eat&amp;object=bacon" />
```

That's the common requirement for any valid XML file.

See [Where can I get a list of the XML document escape characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Answer (score 6):

You can Try using  `&amp;` instead.

Answer (score 4):

In XML an ampersand tells the parser "the data immediately following this ampersand is an entity which needs to be translated." If the data immediately following is not a valid XML entity, then you get this error. If possible, use `&amp;` for your ampersand within the XML.