# Appsetting entry in web.config throwing error for special characters

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have to use the below URL in my **appsettings** in web.config file.

> <add key="ReportUrl" value="http://Myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/MyApplication/Reports/Safeguards+Equipment+and+Supplies+Request&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=True&RequestNumber="/>

The problem occurs because of the colon used in the value of the appsettings. How can I fix the error.

Error shown is as below

> "Application Configuration file "Web.config" is invalid. An error occurred while parsing EntityName...."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error parsing AppSettings value with a query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306399/error-parsing-appsettings-value-with-a-query-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using  **&amp** instead of **&**;

Below are few XML escape characters for your future use!

```
"   &quot;
&   &amp;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
```

Read more here [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)